# Raised-Button gets capitalized instead or normal case in Material UI in Win forms

Tags: c#

I am using Raised-Button in win forms using Material skin but I am facing issue that the button text always gets capitalized instead or normal case.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: While asing a question, it should be descriptive. If you have tried any code, then share it too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Found the issue. They(Material Skin team) are converting to text to ToUpper(). Got their source code from web and Just delete that part of code then create a new .dll referenced it. Now its working fine....

Thanks for your time!...